# Can I use -ErrorVariable while using Out-String in Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to capture the output of a command into output variable in Powershell. The output of the command is in table format which is why I'm using Out-String. Now I need to suppress the error messages which is why I use an error variable to store the error messages. I tried the following things but none of them suppress my error and error gets displayed on screen.

```
$output = $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list() | Out-String -ErrorVariable myErr

$output = $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list() -ErrorVariable myErr | Out-String

$output = $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list() | Out-String 2>&1

$output = $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list() 2>&1 | Out-String
```

Is there a way where I can suppress the errors while using Out-String in a simple way (nothing like try-catch)?

Answer (score 3):

If your `.list()` method is throwing an exception you have two options:

1. Set your `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to `'SilentlyContinue'` or `'Ignore'`

   ```
   $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
   ```
2. Wrap your method call in a try/catch block

   ```
   try
   {
       $output = $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list() | Out-String
   }
   catch
   {
       "Error thrown! $PSItem"
   }
   ```

Do note if your method call is throwing a *terminating* error, you do not have a workaround.

Comment: Aside from _parse_-time errors, _any_ terminating error can be caught with `try` / `catch`  (whether it is _statement_-terminating, such as thrown by a .NET type's method, or a _script_-terminating (thread-terminating), as only thrown by PowerShell's `Throw` statement) .

Comment: Conversely, setting `$ErrorActionPreference` _shouldn't_ affect how statement-terminating errors are treated, but in practice does. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583)

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah.. even I don't get what the different "levels" of error handling are at times; like when you get access denied with `Get-ChildItem`, but it's not script-terminating

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -NoSuch` is statement-terminating, `Get-ChildItem NoSuch` is non-terminating.

Comment: In other words: if it's a _syntax_ error, it's statement-terminating; if it's a _runtime_ error (such as not finding a file or access being denied), it's non-terminating.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more detail to your original question about `-ErrrorVariable`. `-ErrorVariable` is a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6) which you get by default when adding the [CmdletBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6) attribute to the beginning of a function.

The `.list()` is a .Net method not a PowerShell function and thus `-ErrorVariable` does not work with it. You can however write a short function to wrap the .Net method in a small PowerShell function if you would like to use it a lot and would like to leverage some of PowerShell's awesomeness with that method.

Example:

```
function Get-ESXAllowedIPList {

   [CmdletBinding()]
   param($esxcli)

   return $esxcli.network.firewall.ruleset.allowedip.list()

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Get-ESXAllowedIPList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ESXAllowedIPListErrors | Out-String
```